# Writing in Common Styles

Tags: style, essay, article

How do I make my writing sound like a college textbook, a newspaper article, a scientific journal, a blog post, etc, professionally?

Answer (score 2):

Practice pastiches.

Pick examples of the style you want to emulate, and then write something like that.  For instance, take a newspaper article about the opening of a library and write something in its style about the opening of an imaginary school.  Pick a blog entry about visiting parents for the Fourth of July and write one like it about visiting grandparents for Labor Day.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Publishers sometimes have a standard and recommendations on how to write an article for them, as freelance writers submit articles and need to know in what style to write for them.

As there are a myriad of possible styles, I recommend searching for them yourself, (rather than me providing a bunch of links).

This is especially true for news articles, academic papers, and whatever else.
The good way to learn, is to write a draft and then go over it again to match a set of guidelines.